# I cannot understand what are all the different keys for the twitter API

Tags: twitter, twitter-oauth, twitter-api-v2

I cannot understand what is the difference between `API key`, `API key secret`, `Bearer Token`, `Access Token` `Access Secret`. There is also `Client ID` and `Client Secret` which is something very confusing.

I wish to create a Twitter bot, but I find this very confusing. I have tried googling my question, and searching it up on youtube, but I have not found an answer that clears my question.

Answer (score 1):

Admittedly the terms are a bit confusing;but these terms have the same meaning:

Consumer key = Customer key = Api key

Consumer secret = Customer secret = Api secret key

In general, tokens above and Bearer token represent the user that you are making the request on behalf of.

Access token and Access secret - they are Username and Password for your App.

And their usage:

Consumer key, Consumer secret, Access token, Access Secret (or only Access token and Access Secret depending on language and libraries you are using) - these are needed if your software make request to endpoints with POST method, that is if it tweets, replies to a tweet and etc.

If the software make request to endpoints with GET method then authenticating with Bearer Token is enough. Another use of Bearer Token is with Twitter API v2, which only accepts Bearer Token authentication if try to make requests to endpoints of this api.

For more detailed information [Getting Access to Twitter API](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-api/getting-started/getting-access-to-the-twitter-api#:%7E:text=API%20Key%20and%20Secret%3A%20Essentially,Tokens%20or%20App%20Access%20Token.)

Comment: Twitter has an Api Key, which you call the customer key, but then it has a Client key which i would call the customer key. But then if you follow that Twitter documentation it called for a consumer key and Consumer secret, which are absent from the other 4 keys I have. So wtf.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to simply read tweets, then Bearer Token is enough.

If you want to create tweets then you will need to use:
API Key
API Key Secret
Access Token
Access Token Secret

The client Id and client secret are not require.

There's a full articl here:
https://pythonhowtoprogram.com/how-to-build-a-twitter-bot-with-python-and-twitter-api-v2/